# How to use `mongo DB` data for analysis in Node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bigdata

I have been using `MongoDB` as a database for my `nodejs` application.
Now i want to use that data for some analytics on my dashboard page.

Problem is its lot of data , i want analytics which will also be using a fair big amount of data and surely it will decrease speed of my `server`.

Like i have a question which is been answered million times by different users and i want to show average time taken by users to solve that question, So if i directly use `aggregation` in `mongo` it will take lot of time.

So what should i do? 
Should i use some different application which will keep using that data from my database and then serve to my `nodejs` server?
And what are best tools to do that e.g. `superset` from `apache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you learn how to use mongoDB indexing properly the speed for query result increases. And using aggregation will decrease the amount of request needed by client apps  to send to your server which is mostly benifitial for mobile clients.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: i have already implemented indexing on collections, but the amount of data is huge. I needed it for Business intelligence and other analytics